# How to generate a series of iterable slots in a template notebook?

Tags: templates, slot

How can I generate a seires of iterable slots in template notebook I can later loop over and assign values to? For example:
[image]

I could generate this manually by typing out each one. However, it gets very tedious if a lot of slots need to be generated. How can I automate this? Can I use repeating block?

Comment: You could use `CellPrint[]` and `Defer[]` for this...

Comment: Template notebooks toolbars' containg "Repeating Block" button, you can create only the first set and tell it to iterate over e.g. `Range[5]`. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NotebookPut[
  Notebook[Flatten[{Cell[ToString@#, "Subsection"], 
       Cell["A=" <> ToString@#, "Input"]} & /@ Range@10]]];
```

Actually I don't think I get your point. Will this code solve your problem?

It will create a new notebook with 10 sections in it. In each section, there'll be one subtitle cell and one content cell, where you can modify its content.

Is that what you need?